# Excluding certain ProtoMembers during the Schema generation using protobuf-net

Tags: c#, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

An issue with DateTime Protobuf serialization & Deserialization.

---

*A pseudo implementation of the code look like below, actual class used for serialization have multiple child classes and DateTime fields exist in multiple places in the multiple child classes.*

---

in v1.0 of our product we have class like,

```
[ProtoContract]
public class DateTimeTest
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public DateTime LastDateTime { get; set; }
}
```

We have allowed customer to persist the data as protobuf serialized files. However later we found out that we were losing the **DateTime's Kind information** on deserialization.

We found out that, if we use "**DataFormat.WellKnown**" the issue can be solved.
so we updated our class like below in v2.0 of our product.

```
[ProtoContract]
public class DateTimeTest
{
    [ProtoMember(1, DataFormat = DataFormat.WellKnown)]
    public DateTime LastDateTime { get; set; }
}
```

Even though it solve the issues for the current users, we **broke the existing users ability to deserialize** the v1.0 serialized data.

To address this issue we again updated our class like as below in a hotfix to v2

```
[ProtoContract]
public class DateTimeTest
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    private DateTime LastDateTime_OLD
    {
        get => LastDateTime; 
        set => LastDateTime = DateTime.SpecifyKind(value, DateTimeKind.Utc); //We save date in utc always, so setting Kind on v1.0 data deserialization.
    }

    private bool ShouldSerializeLastDateTime_OLD() => false;
    
    [ProtoMember(2, DataFormat = DataFormat.WellKnown)]
    public DateTime LastDateTime { get; set; }
}
```

Now the Issue with DateTime serialization & deserialization **is solved** for us.

Now **some other product written using C++** need to read the protobuf serialized data, so they requested us for **Proto schema file**.

We generated schema using

```
RuntimeTypeModel.Default.GetSchema(typeof(DateTimeTest), ProtoSyntax.Proto3);
```

And schema look like below

```
syntax = "proto3";
import "protobuf-net/bcl.proto"; // schema for protobuf-net's handling of core .NET types
import "google/protobuf/timestamp.proto";
message DateTimeTest {
   .bcl.DateTime LastDateTime_cmf12 = 1;
   .google.protobuf.Timestamp LastDateTime = 2;
}
```

now we need to **hand correct the schmea and remove all "bcl" lines.**

So the question, is there any way to **exclude certain ProtoMember from schema generation?**
or **may be exclude private ProtoMember field** in my case.

```
[ProtoMember(1)]
private DateTime LastDateTime_OLD
{
    get => LastDateTime; 
    set => LastDateTime = DateTime.SpecifyKind(value, DateTimeKind.Utc);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No such feature currently exists. However, it is probably very little effort to add some kind of callback API to the existing context object, and use that to exclude members based on your own rules.  I'd happily consider a PR that adds such.

Answer (score 0):

The way I have handled things like this is to simply create a new class for the new schema, and label each class appropriately. This does cause some duplication, but situations like this should hopefully be fairly rare.

You would need to consider if any external clients would ever need to serialize a object. If so you would run into the same issue with v1.0 clients if you remove `LastDateTime_OLD`. Even if you decide now that no c++ clients do need to serialize, keep in mind that such a decision might change in the future, so you might need to be very clear in comments and documentation about incompatibility issues like this.

Comment: Code in question is a pseudo implementation for simplicity. Original code is very complex with multiple classes and DateTime field exits in multiple child classes in the a middle of the classes hierarchy. So duplicating them is not an easy option.